# how to decode gzip webclient response spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient, spring-webclient

```java
WebClient.create().method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(url)
                .queryParam(attribute1, attribute1)
                .queryParam(attribute2, attribute2)
                .build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .headers(header -> {
                    header.add("Authorization", authHeaders);
                    header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    header.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
                }).retrieve().bodyToMono(Object.class);
```

Comment: @Brian Clozel please answer my above query.